# Export PowerPoint slides into java.awt.Graphics2D

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

i started a test to convert a ppt document to jpeg or png image. i use java to test.
follow the instruction on the apache web: http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/how-to-shapes.html#Render, and the code:

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("slideshow.ppt");
        SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow(is);
        is.close();

        Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();

        Slide[] slide = ppt.getSlides();
        for (int i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {

            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(pgsize.width, pgsize.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
            //clear the drawing area
            graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
            graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));

            //render
            slide[i].draw(graphics);

            //save the output
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("slide-"  + (i+1) + ".png");
            javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(img, "png", out);
            out.close();
        }
```

in the ppt doc, i just type the "hello world", than i run the java program, and the png image generated successfully. but i open the image with ACDsee software to view the image, but the "helloworld" didn't appear in the png image. what is the matter? Can anyone here give me some advice? you can also test by yourself to look at the result, pls let me know if you have got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you aren't doing anything at all with your `BufferedImage`.  You are simply filling the image with white and saving it to a file.

Comment: flafla2: you can test this by following the instruction on apache web :  http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/how-to-shapes.html#Render, and pls let me know your result.